# How to create image or pdf from html having css filters?

Tags: javascript, php, css, pdf-generation

I want to create an image or pdf from a html. The html consist of images with css filters like sepia, gray-scale etc. So it would be better if anyone have worked on that.

```
<img class="dj_rot" src="/940/images/photos.png" style="filter: sepia(1);">
<img class="dj_rot" src="/940/images/photos.png" style="filter: grayscale(1);">
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

You could use "html2canvas" is a opensource script that allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

You will see many examples of how to use in the same webpage

If you want to create a PDF you could use a jsPDF is another option based on Javascript

http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Also you will find the documentation with examples and source code

If it is not enough you could use and API that allow that, You only need to establish a URL and then you receive the image

```
https://screenshotlayer.com/
```

Screenshotlayer (Free, Powerful Screenshot API)
url2png (Screenshots as a Service)
urlbox.io (Website Screenshot as a Service API urlbox)
screenshotmachine (Screenshot machine)
Browshot (Service for real time website screenshots)

You could review a link with more information
What's the best website screenshot capture API?

```
https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-website-screenshot-capture-API
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Luis,

Yes, these are open source but none of them provides css filters in output. I have tried html2canvas, jspdf and mpdf. The result are same. If i try to create a canvas with an image and add filters then it shows on console that css has been applied but not in screen or pdf.

Comment: Right, In the majority of cases the problem is that Styles has not been rendered correctly, you could try to use and API for generate the same PDF, I am going to write some of them above

Comment: Screenshotlayer can be used but it is paid, not open source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a screenshot of the HTML? To take a screenshot you should hit command+shift+4. The number 3 takes a screenshot of the entire screen, while the number 4 allows you to select what it will take a screenshot of.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jennifer.
I'm sorry, I didn't tell the technology. Actually I want this functionality in my programming using language js or php.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I was confused by why you weren't using a simple screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pdf converting tools like html2pdf of mPDF for PHP.
I have used html2pdf successfully in the past, but I am pretty sure both of them have a good support for CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply gm08,

I have tried both but output doesn't show css filters. Only images can be shown in pdf files.
I have also asked mpdf on github. Please find my issue link.
[link]https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/362

Comment: For html2canvas : [link]https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/493
They also does not support the css filters.